# How do i center the custom svg icon on the road

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I just want to ask i have svg icon it will not center on the road it shows always on the side of the road unlike the predefined path (arrow) by google map it shows on the center of the map.how can i make it center on the road just like on the predefined path by google map.

here is my jsfiddle

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/jemz24/kSKGs/6/)

```
var iconcar = {
   path: "M17.402,0H5.643C2.526,0,0,3.467,0,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759c3.116,0,5.644-2.527,5.644-5.644 V6.584C23.044,3.467,20.518,0,17.402,0z M22.057,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L22.057,14.188z M20.625,10.773 c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H4.638l-2.222-8.51C2.417,10.773,11.3,7.755,20.625,10.773z M3.748,21.713v4.492l-2.73-0.349 V14.502L3.748,21.713z M1.018,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L1.018,37.938z M2.575,40.882l2.218-3.336h13.771l2.219,3.336H2.575z M19.328,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L19.328,35.805z",

   scale: .8
    }
    var carPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        geodesic : true,
        strokeColor : '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity : 1.0,
        strokeWeight : 2,
        icons: [{
          icon: iconcar,
            scale: .8,   
          offset: '100%'
        }],
    });
    var carPath = new google.maps.MVCArray();
    for ( var i = 0; i < path_start.length; i++) {
        if(i === 0) {
            carPath.push(path_start[i]);
            carPolyline.setPath(carPath);
        } else {
            setTimeout((function(latLng) {
                return function() {

                    carPath.push(latLng);
                    map.setCenter(latLng);
                };
            })(path_start[i]), 100 * i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set different anchor point, for example:

```
var iconcar = {
       anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 50),
       path:
   ...
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kSKGs/7/)

This anchors it a the front center of the "car":

```
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 0),
```

[anchored at the front center of the car](http://jsfiddle.net/kSKGs/8/)